# scanf validation sits and waits for another input. Why?

Tags: c

I was working on this sample exercise, and everything works as I would like it to, but there is one behavior I don't understand.

When providing input: if I make consecutive invalid entries everything seems to work great. But if I enter a number different from 1,2,3 in the case of the first question, or 1,2 in the case of the second question, the program just sits there until a new input is given. If another invalid entry is made, it goes back to the error "invalid entry" message, and if an appropriate number is entered, everything moves along fine.

I do not understand why it stops to wait for a second input...anyone?

Thanks guys.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int getInt(const char *prompt)
{
    int value;
    printf("%s",prompt);
    while (scanf("%d", &value) !=1)
    {
      printf("Your entry is invalid.\nGive it another try: %s", prompt);
      getchar();
      scanf("%d", &value);
    }
    return value;
}

int main() {

int wood_type, table_size, table_price;

printf("Please enter " );
wood_type = getInt("1 for Pine, 2 for Oak, and 3 for Mahogany: ");

printf("Please enter ");
table_size = getInt("1 for large, 2 for small: ");

printf("\n");

switch (wood_type) {
   case 1:
        table_price = (table_size == 1)? 135:100;
        printf("The cost of for your new table is: $%i", table_price);
        break;

    case 2:
        table_price = (table_size == 1)? 260:225;
        printf("The cost of for your new table is: $%i", table_price);
        break;

    case 3:
        table_price = (table_size == 1)? 345:310;
        printf("The cost of for your new table is: $%i", table_price);
        break;

    default:
        table_price = 0;
        printf("The cost of for your new table is: $%i", table_price);
        break;

}
}
```

Comment: Bro, I could not understand your problem in my machine your code runs well .. if i supply 1 or 2 or 3 in first row then 1 or 2 in second it prints some amt of cash .. and if input in 1 row is other than 1 2 3 the prints 0 and lastly if in 1 st row my input is 1 2 3 and in 2nd row its not 1 or 2 then also some amount is printed . Am i missing something . I read your code and tried in my machine. I think i do not understand your question

Comment: For the first input, try entering a letter, and then the number 5. After you enter 5, it leaves me hanging there until I either enter another letter, or a 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: Oh! yea that hang me too ... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely need to flush your input buffer (especially with multiple `scanf` calls in a function). After scanf, a newline `'\n'` remains in the input buffer. `fflush` does **NOT** do this, so you need to do it manually. A simple `do...while` loop works. Give it a try:

**edit:**

```
static int getInt(const char *prompt)
{
    int value;
    int c;

    while (printf (prompt) && scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
    {
        do { c = getchar(); } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF );              // flush input
        printf ("Invalid Entry, Try Again...");
    }

    return value;
}
```

The blank line you get if you enter **nothing** is the normal behavior of `scanf`. It is waiting for input  (**some input**). If you want your routine to immediately prompt again in the case the `[Enter]` key is pressed, then you need to use another routine to read `stdin` like (`getline` or `fgets`). `getline` is preferred as it returns the number of characters read (which you can test). You can then use `atoi` (in `<stdlib.h>`) to convert the string value to an integer. This will give you the flexibility you need.

**example:**

```
int newgetInt (char *prompt)
{
    char *line = NULL;      /* pointer to use with getline ()       */
    ssize_t read = 0;       /* number of characters read            */
    size_t n = 0;           /* numer of chars to read, 0 no limit   */
    static int num = 0;     /* number result                        */

    while (printf ("\n %s ", prompt) && (read = getline (&line, &n, stdin)) != -1)
    {
        if ((num = atoi (line)))
            break;
        else
            printf ("Invalid Input, Try Again...\n");
    }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: :( I tried but things actually got worse...now when I enter a number that is not 1,2,3 it actually takes two more invalid entries to get back to the error message...
And I thought that's what that getchar() was doing for me in the middle of the loop? (getting rid of "\n' left behind)

Comment: I see the issue - hold on a second and I'll have an answer :)

Comment: That worked great. Thanks so much! Whats the difference in having the printf as part of the while statement instead of inside the loop code? And Xcode throws me a warning that value might not be initialized there...what is that about?

Comment: That means that it is looking at an uninitialized value. Easy cure, give all variables an initial value. I have added another function to the answer -- give it a look.

Comment: Note that the code in the plain `getInt()` function does not handle EOF very well.  The `scanf()` returns EOF, which is not 1, so it goes into the body of the loop; the `do while` loop terminates on the first iteration, the message is printed, and control goes back to the top of the outer loop.  The `newgetInt` will not allow you to enter zero as a valid number.  It also should probably not have `num` as a static variable (doing so means that you will get the last number returned over and over again on EOF).  Neither function has a way to indicate EOF to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

If some invalid input is entered, it stays in the input buffer. 
The invalid input must be extracted before the `scanf` function is completed.

A better method is to get the whole line of input then work on that line.

First, put that input line into a temporary array using `fgets()`,
then use `sscanf()` (safer than `scanf` because it guards against overflow).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char tempbuff[50];
    int result, d , value;

    do
    {
        printf("Give me a number: ");
        fgets( tempbuff, sizeof(tempbuff), stdin );  //gets string, puts it into tempbuff via stdin

        result = sscanf(tempbuff, "%d", &value);     //result of taking buffer scanning it into value

        if (result < 1){                             //scanf can return 0, # of matched conversions,
                                                     //(1 in this case), or EOF.
            printf("You didn't type a number!\n");
        }
    }while (result < 1);

    //some code

    return 0;
}
```

Knowledge from: http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2008/02/07/scanf-and-why-you-should-avoid-using-it/