# Checking input type without quitting the program and restarting it

Tags: c

I have a requirement to get two integers and add and print the added value. I wrote a working program. Another requirement is to check whether the input value is other than integer and if it is other than integer, without closing the program, it should again ask for the inputs.

C Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a,b,c;

    printf("This is a Addition program");

    printf("\n Enter value of a:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("\n Enter value of b:");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    c=a+b;

    printf("\n The added value is %d",c);
}
```

Comment: @KristerAndersson That actually makes sense. check if it is other than integer(double, float, string) and if it is (other than integer) do x

Comment: if it is other integer it should not close the program instead it should give a customized message and ask for the input again.

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: enclose everything in `main` in a `while(1){...}` and `if(b>a)break;` just before the `}` of the `while`.

Comment: @KristerAndersson Yeah. I understand what they're asking. 'I wrote a working code' basically I wrote code that works

Comment: Is anybody answering me?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @elayaraja , I did. Also,you'll get better responses if you include your code(what you have done till now).

Comment: @CoolGuy I have added the code. I haven't checked the input , I need idea to do the requirement I have.

Comment: @MaheshBansod how to have input validation and restart the program if the validation fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that will completely fulfil your requirement. Yesterday [David C Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26316030/15168) to the same basic [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315822/scanf-validation-sits-and-waits-for-another-input-why) in Stack Overflow.

This code is basically what David provided:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int getInt(const char *prompt)
{
    int value;
    char c;

    while(printf("%s",prompt) && scanf("%d", &value) !=1)
    {
     do { c = getchar(); } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF );              // flush input
            printf ("Invalid Entry, Try Again...\n");
    }

    return value;
}

int sum(int a , int b) {  return ( a + b ); }

int main(){

    int a , b;

    a = getInt("Please enter a number");
    b = getInt("Please enter a number");

    printf("Sum is :%d" , sum(a,b));

}
```

The function **getInt** check the input and yells for the wrong input.

Comment: I have copied the code .. but could not find the link.

Comment: The function is a good idea; it saves repeating a non-negligible quantity of code.  The `while (print prompt && scanf() != 1)` loop is (basically) good too.  However, if the function gets EOF, it is going to run for a long time.  You probably need to capture the return from `scanf()` and if it is EOF, arrange to return (but remember to set `value` to a deterministic value. _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_  You have a problem with EOF detection in the `do { ... } while ();` loop.  Either you will misdetect EOF when the user types a valid character (often ÿ, y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS), or you will never detect EOF at all depending on whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: That is good info, and info I would not have uncovered regardless of how long I searched. The days of simple ASCII, it seems, are over..

Comment: `do { c = getchar(); } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF );` is an infinite loop when the `stdin` is closed and `char` is _unsigned_.  Use `int c;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This program will do what you want

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()  //use int not void
{
    int a,b,c;

    printf("This is a Addition program");

    printf("\n Enter value of a:");
    while(scanf("%d",&a)==0)
    {
        printf("\n Invalid input.Try again:");
        getchar(); // clear the previous input
    }
    printf("\n Enter value of b:");
    while(scanf("%d",&b)==0)
    {
        printf("\n Invalid input.Try again:");
        getchar(); // clear the previous input
    }
    c=a+b;

    printf("\n The added value is %d",c);

    return 0;  // because main returns int
}
```

[`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) returns the number of successfully read items, so it will return 1 in your case if a valid value was entered. If not, an invalid integer value was entered and `scanf` will return 0.

Comment: If the user types `a` instead of a number, the program is going to run forever.  You need to clear the erroneous input.  The result output should be terminated with a newline.  For safety, it should also report on the two numbers being added: `printf("The result of %d + %d = %d\n", a, b, c);`.  I think it is a good idea to provide an upper limit (like 10 attempts) on getting a valid input.  If the user hasn't succeeded in 10 attempts, they probably aren't going to.

Comment: In the old days, I prefered the following test : `scanf("%d%1s", &a, &c) == 1` (with `char c;` declared above) : it not only test that the input *begins* by an integer, but also that it *only contains* an integer ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ,You are right. Now it works just fine! I don't think any user will enter incorrectly for over 10 times...

Comment: @SergeBallesta: the `if (scanf("%d%1s", &a, &c) == 1)` test seems dubious on several counts. First, the `1s` requires two characters, so you need `char c[2]`, so you don't need the `&` in `&c`.  Next, the `%1s` skips white space until it reads something other than white space; it will eat blanks, tabs and newlines until you type a letter or digit. That is unlikely to be the required behaviour; it is really nasty behaviour for an interactive program. And, unless the user indicates EOF (typing control-D, for example), the string input isn't going to fail so you won't get 1 returned by `scanf()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you **are** right for the `char c[2]` ... But I did use it in interactive programs to force input to be numbers only. I'm not sure that `1 abc` for the last input is correct. It will choke with  the `"%d1s"` trick, but go fine with a simple `"%d"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fgets()/sscanf()/strto...()` rather than `scanf()`.

`scanf()` parses and performs input in the same function and does not well handle unexpected input.  Use `fgets()` for user input and *then* scan/parse.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getint(const char *prompt) {
  char buf[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT];
  while (1) {
    fputs(prompt, stdout);
    fflush(stdout);
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
      // sample handling of unexpected input issue.
      // Value to return of EOF or IO error
      return INT_MIN;
    }
    /// strtol() is another option
    int i, n;
    // " %n" notes offset of non-white-space after the numebr.
    if (1 == sscanf(buf, "%d %n", &i, &n) && buf[n] == '\0') {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int a, b, c;

  printf("This is a Addition program");
  a = getint("\n Enter value of a:");
  b = getint("\n Enter value of b:");

  c = a + b;
  printf("\n The added value is %d", c);
  return 0;
}
```