# Present error messages for invalid data entry

Tags: c, string, char, int

This is my first Project (kind of a text based game). How do I present error messages when text is entered in an area where numbers are prompted and vice versa. Or possibly the ability to reject improper input altogether.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char Name[20];
    char q1;
    int q2[2],q3[2];
    float qT[3];
    for(q1='n';q1!='y';)
    {
        printf("What is your name?\n");
        gets(Name);
        printf("You have entered: ");
        puts(Name);
        printf("Is this okay? [y/n]\n");
        scanf("%s",&q1);
        if(q1!='y'&&q1!='n')
            printf("User error: '%c' not recognized.\nPlease enter 'y' to         continue or 'n' to edit your name\n",&q1);
        if(q1!='y'&&q1!='n')
            scanf("%s",&q1);
    }
    printf("Okay, %s.",Name);
    printf(" Out of the three choices which would you like to do most?\n1.      Start a garden.\n2. Build a house.\n3. Travel to somewhere you've never been.\n");
    scanf("%d",q2);
    for (;q2[0]>3||q2[0]<1;)
    {
        printf("User error: '%c' not recognized.\nPlease enter one of the    options given.",q2);
        scanf("%d",q2);
    }
    if(q2[0]==1)
        printf("What would you plant in your garden?\n1. Flowers\n2. Vegetables\n3. Fruit and Berries\n");
    else
        if(q2[0]==2)
            printf("Where would you build your house?\n1. In the Mountains\n2. In the Desert\n3. By the Sea\n");
        else
            if(q2[0]==3)
                printf("What would bring you to such a place?\n1. New faces and cultures\n2. Treasures and adventure\n3. Escape from the ordinary\n");
            else
                for(;q2[0]>3||q2[0]<1;)
                {
                    printf("User error: '%c' not recognized.\nPlease enter one of the options given.",&q2);
                    scanf("%d",q3);
                }
    scanf("%d",q3);
    qT[0]=(q2[0]*12)/q3[0];
    printf("%f",qT[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Super question title.

Comment: [Don't use `gets()`. Ever.](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1049157810&id=1043284351) `char q1; scanf("%s",&q1);` is wrong (scanf will add a null byte at the next location, causing undefined behaviour).

Comment: You might want to put your question before your code.

Comment: Can yo elaborate on what you need exactly , so if the user enters char while they're supposed to enter number you want to handle that and give error message?

Comment: `scanf` already does that for you. Since you have used `%d` then `scanf` will expect an integer. If a non-integer is entered `scanf` will return 0 (instead of 1).

Comment: Code like `getint()` may help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26333071/2410359) to read a number.